# Subset a dataframe using a string of column names

Tags: r

I need to subset a dataframe (df) by a string of columns names that I have created - not sure how to inject this into a subet..?

for example

```
colstoKeep is a character string:
"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"
```

how do I push this into a subset function

```
df<- df[colstoKeep]
```

I'm sure this is easy.? because the above doesn't work.

Comment: df[, c("A","B","X","T"]  that is, df = data.frame, square bracketes, comma, and A etc are the column names.

Comment: Yeah but I have >1000 col names all collapsed intob a string so I want to input the string name, not the physical columns typed in there...

Comment: Then I'm confused.  What is the exact value of `colsToKeep`?  `"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"` is not a valid R object.

Comment: its a character...one long character, id like to place that long char object inside a subset function.

Comment: You were just missing the comma. Remember, data.frame square bracket rows comma columns close square bracket.  Leaving the rows blank means show all rows.

Comment: @user1945827 The command `df[colstoKeep]` is valid for data frames. You don't need the comma.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein didn't know that.  Then the OPs character string is corrupted and doesn't represent the column names.

Comment: That does work...saying undefined columns selected...with or without the comma...I even tried making the character " c("col1", col2".....) " and injecting that in and it still won't work.

Comment: Is it a *single* string containing multiple column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df  <- data.frame(A=seq(1:5),B=seq(5:1),C=seq(1:5))
df

colsToKeep <- "\"A\", \"C\""
```

If I understand your question correctly, your `colsToKeep` variable is a string as given above.  In order to extract the variables, you will have to convert that into a vector.  If I've used the right format, you can do that with the following code.

```
library(magrittr)
colsToKeepVector <- 
  strsplit(colsToKeep, ",") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  trimws() %>%
  gsub("\"", "", .)

df[colsToKeepVector]
```

However, if I'm also understanding that you had a vector that you collapsed to a string (`paste(..., collapse = ", ")`?), I would strongly advise you *not* to do that.

(Edited to match the string format in the question)

Answer (score 0):

```
df  <- data.frame(A=seq(1:5),B=seq(5:1),C=seq(1:5))
df
  A B C
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
4 4 4 4
5 5 5 5

cols_to_keep  <- c("A","C")
df[,cols_to_keep]
  A C
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4 4
5 5 5
```

Comment: ColstoKeep was formed from one long vector of column names that I collapsed with \",\" separation to achieve one long character of col names. I then need to use that Character to subset a df to leave only those Cols available in that df.

Comment: If I applied your process to my example would cols_to_keep return "AC", rather than "A" "C"?  If so, that is the reason it will not work.  You need to have your column names as separate entities.

Comment: colstokeep <- paste(df$COLS,collapse="\",\"") that provides a string of col names separated with ","....ie a","b","c","d id then like to take that string and somehow subset another df using it

Comment: when I do the following, paste(colnames(df), collapse="\",\"") I get "A\",\"B\",\"C" what does the first ten characters of your string look like?  What does your str(colstokeep) look like?